# Should I use a JWT token for authenticating a game's player?

Tags: security, authentication, game-development, jwt

I'm using Unity, PHP and MySQL to make my game, and I've already added simple registration and login to my game.
But I have a question - In game development I also should use JWT token to authorize user operations?

I'm just wondering how these pieces would work together. My game will have some online operations like trade, or fight with others, etc. Are MMO games using JWT tokens, or other solutions I should look at as well?

Comment: While not a direct answer, there is a [great answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/46595) related to your question on the gamedev exchange.